# How to reevaluate a powershell variable fetched from a file

Tags: powershell, csv, profile

I'm using a CSV file and Import-Csv to get a bunch of custom aliases and paths. I'm doing this so that I can do RUN  and the path will be executed through Invoke-Item.

I can do this in the command shell window too to open the profile ps1 using: Invoke-Item $PROFILE - Which then starts the profile ps1 in notepad.

But I wanna use my run function. So I specify the alias "profile" in the CSV along with the path as "$PROFILE" which should then call "Invoke-Item $profile" - Except when I use it through the CSV, $profile remains a text and doesn't get evaluated.

Is there a way to reevaluate a variable in a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can evaluate it with the `Invoke-Expression` cmdlet (or its alias 'iex'):

```
Invoke-Item (iex "$profile")
```

Comment: Nice one - I have a followup question though. In 1 case I need to call a $profile variable - IEX solves this for me, so that I can get $profile evaluated. Now the other cases I need to run programs - So I supply a path. Now I added iex - The paths fail if they contain a space, do you know why? "The term 'C:\Program' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file"

Comment: Try to enclose the path in another set of quotes.